# Qt 5.6 Beta Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.6

I have installed this

http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0-beta/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015-5.6.0-beta.exe.mirrorlist

And tried it using this extension on VS

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c89ff880-8509-47a4-a262-e4fa07168408

The extension detects the Qt version (5.6) but will give this error

This Qt version uses an unsupported makefile generator (used: MSVC.NETMSBUILD, supported: MSVC.NET, MSBUILD)

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 13):

The problem seems to be a bug in the extension that concatenates the MAKEFILE_GENERATOR settings.

You might try the following workaround:
In QT5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf
line 14 should read:
MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = MSVC.NET

After commenting out this line, I was able to add QT Version 5.6.0 via QT5->Options->QT Versions->Add without problem

Everything worked fine after that.

Comment: Also worth checking msvc-base.conf in the same folder. 

For some reason it concatenates MAKEFILE_GENERATOR from both files, so I had to comment out the line that defines MAKEFILE_GENERATOR in msvc-base.conf.

Comment: @Joe Cool: Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Test it as well , i have already asked the Qt guys they said that the updated version of Qt addin for vs2015 will be out with the release version of qt 5.6.

i quess they don't care about vs2015 that much since they got their own tool to advertise (qtcreator)

Comment: What do you mean by "Test it as well"?

Comment: The thing is that the API used for the plugin is not supported in VS2015 anymore. Thus, the plugin has to be completly rewritten - and that will take some time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this change https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/124917/ which synchronizes settings between classic and WinRT applications.

The workaround I found is in C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf. Qt 5.6.0 splits all the version-specific changes into a separate file msvc-base.conf. If you copy the contents of this file and replace the line "include(msvc- base.conf)" in mscv-desktop.conf then Qt5Package recognises the Qt 5.6.0 Beta with no problems.

Note this still needs to be fixed in Qt5Package.