# Qt 5.6 VS 2015 Add-in asks to specify default version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5.6

My story starts same as here [Qt 5.6 VS 2015 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405207/qt-5-6-beta-visual-studio-2015)

> I have installed this
>
> http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0-beta/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015-5.6.0-beta.exe.mirrorlist
>
> And tried it using this extension on VS
>
> https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c89ff880-8509-47a4-a262-e4fa07168408

I've faced the same problem as described in that question. And the answer solved my problem as well.

But now I have another error. I've searched on the net but couldn't find anything related to. By now, QT path in Qt Add-in is set. Every time I click 'Open .pro project' it tells me

```
The following error occurred:
The default Qt version does not support Visual Studio 2015.
In order to import .pro files specify a Qt version >=5.2 as default.
```

### So, the question is how to specify a Qt version. Probably it's one line in a config file, but in which one?

Comment: Do you have VS 2015? I have Visual Studio 2013, same problem, only solution I found was to downgrade to Qt5.5.1. I really think it is a Qt bug in their config files

Comment: If you downgrade to Qt5.5.1, configure your project, then change the Qt version to Qt5.6, it works... Strange

Comment: Great, that you've noticed that. Can be useful for someone